# Ansible: postgresql_db restore hangs

Tags: postgresql, ansible, psql

using the below script for the DB restore from a sql

```
- name: Copy database dump file from Ansible Control tower to DB server
  copy:
    src: dump.sql
    dest: /home/ubuntu/

- name: Import the DB
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: <>
    login_user: <>
    state: restore
    target: /home/ubuntu/dump.sql
```

It took around 2 hours all showing good but at the second play it got stuck and not showing any errors, it hangs completely.

Comment: Check if it's waiting for a lock, e.g. looking at `pg_stat_activity`